# Delombok: Preserve line breaks

Tags: lombok

I'm compiling delomboked java files while releasing the jar file.
Having code like below :

```java
getSomeStream()
.map(v->...)
.filter(v->...)
.flatMap(v->...)
.reduce((s,a)->....)
```

gets delomboked to single line :

```java
getSomeStream().map(v->...).filter(v->...).flatMap(v->...).reduce((s,a)->....)
```

which is impossible to debug.
Running delombok with `-f pretty` doesn't solve this.

Is there any option to keep the code human-readable ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by running google java format on delomboked  sources :

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.github.sherter.google-java-format' version '0.9'
    id "io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok" version "4.0.0"
}
task delombok(type: DelombokTask) {
    ext.outputDir = file("$buildDir/delombok")
    outputs.dir(outputDir)
    sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each {
        inputs.dir(it)
        args(it, "-d", outputDir)
    }
    doFirst {
        outputDir.deleteDir()
    }
}
googleJavaFormat {
    toolVersion = '1.9'
    source =  "$buildDir/delombok"
    include '**/*.java'
}

tasks.googleJavaFormat{
    dependsOn delombok
}
```

Result:

Original code snippet:

```java
for (Map.Entry<String,QueryBuilder> e : aliases.entrySet()) {
            if (!restTemplate
                    .indexOps(resourcesIndices)
                    .getAliases(e.getKey())
                    .containsKey(resourcesIndices.getIndexName())) {

                final boolean acknowledged = restTemplate
                        .indexOps(resourcesIndices)
                        .alias(new AliasActions(new AliasAction.Add(
                                AliasActionParameters.builder()
                                        .withAliases(e.getKey())
                                        .withIndices(resourcesIndices.getIndexName())
                                        .withFilterQuery(new NativeSearchQuery(e.getValue()))
                                        .build()

                        )));
                if (!acknowledged) {
                    throw new BeanCreationException("Failed to  create alias");
                }
            }
        }
```

Delomboked:

```java
for (Map.Entry<String, QueryBuilder> e : aliases.entrySet()) {
            if (!restTemplate.indexOps(resourcesIndices).getAliases(e.getKey()).containsKey(resourcesIndices.getIndexName())) {
                final boolean acknowledged = restTemplate.indexOps(resourcesIndices).alias(new AliasActions(new AliasAction.Add(AliasActionParameters.builder().withAliases(e.getKey()).withIndices(resourcesIndices.getIndexName()).withFilterQuery(new NativeSearchQuery(e.getValue())).build())));
                if (!acknowledged) {
                    throw new BeanCreationException("Failed to  create alias");
                }
            }
        }
```

Google  formatted

```java
for (Map.Entry<String, QueryBuilder> e : aliases.entrySet()) {
      if (!restTemplate
          .indexOps(resourcesIndices)
          .getAliases(e.getKey())
          .containsKey(resourcesIndices.getIndexName())) {
        final boolean acknowledged =
            restTemplate
                .indexOps(resourcesIndices)
                .alias(
                    new AliasActions(
                        new AliasAction.Add(
                            AliasActionParameters.builder()
                                .withAliases(e.getKey())
                                .withIndices(resourcesIndices.getIndexName())
                                .withFilterQuery(new NativeSearchQuery(e.getValue()))
                                .build())));
        if (!acknowledged) {
          throw new BeanCreationException("Failed to  create alias");
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure: I am a lombok maintainer.

I understand the request, but unfortunately we don't have easy access to the original line breaks.

Delombok generates an output based on the Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) and some formatting options. The AST is produced by the parser.

Since we have the AST, delombok can generate a new file using relatively easy formatting rules.

I am not saying it is impossible to try and find the line endings in the original source file, but it is not trivial.

Based on your comment regarding debugging, do you mean the only useful information you get is the line number?

I can imagine that we add an option to always insert line breaks after a "select", so that call chains are always spread over multiple lines. We could even include method call inside arguments to be put on their own line.

Comment: Thanks for reply @roel-spilker. Yes, line number would be enough. I want to be able to set the breakpoint and specific line easily. I'll try to  reformat the delomboked code with `google-java-format-1.9-all-deps.jar` to solve this ...